# How to publish package to npm without revealing the code

Tags: npm-publish

I'm trying to publish package to npm but don't want that who using the package be able to see the code. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since `npm` is pretty much used to distribute JavaScript+CSS files, there is nothing you can do about it. Your code is going to be seen by whoever uses it or executes it.

You might be able to mitigate this somehow by using [minifiers](https://www.minifier.org) or [obfuscators](https://obfuscator.io) though.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile your code e.g. to `dist` folder and then run `npm publish` in the `dist` directory. Users then can see only what will be placed in the dist folder (compiled code). However, I think that this is not good practice.

You can also consider [private npm packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-private-packages) to distribute your packages only to those who you want.